# should have done

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

Is it possible to use “***should have done***” to state something which will happen in the future? What I’ve read in my grammar textbook is that this structure is used to state something which happened in the past, but I heard this structure in a conversation. Here is the sentence I heard during the conversation:

> Well, check with me tomorrow morning. I ***should've found*** something by then. It might not be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

**Should have** can be used both retrospectively to reflect on an action that one ought to have taken (and didn't) - or to express a view about a future outcome in the sense of **it is likely that**.

In your example **should have** (plus past participle) is used in this second sense.

You will find a useful explanation and examples at the website listed below.

https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/could-have-should-have-would-have.html